# upload image to db using image url (DJANGO)

Tags: python, html, django, database, django-forms

Im new to django and im trying to upload a specific image from html form to the django database using its url. I found multiple ways to do so, but they all use the "browse" button and makes the user manually choose which image to upload (see image below). Is there a way to automatically look for and upload a specific image thats already in my device using image url?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

insert directly to the database file in the same directory with manage.py **(db.sqlite3**) with python code .

*assumming that you didn't change anything in the settings, Django will use sqlite as a default database*.

if you already have the list for image url than just *for loop* to convert image to binary and `INSERT` to database with ***sqlite3*** python library.

I also recommend to use ***DB Browser for SQLite*** to check the database.

Answer (score 0):

##### Follow this step to Upload image in database (Django)

```
#------- Image & Files Handel in Dajngo -----

# --------- Insert Image in Table  ---------
# Note:- You Need to install pillow module for handling image file (pip install pillow)
#      - You Need to write (request.FILES) for insert image or other files insert database
#      - You Need to write (enctype="multipart/form-data") in HTML Page in <form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data"></form> tag


# --------- Show Image in Html   ---------

# Add Code in Project (urls.py)
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path,include

from django.conf import settings # --------> this
from django.conf.urls.static import static # --------> this

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', include('myapp.urls')),
]+static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT) # --------> this

# Add Code in Project (settings.py)
MEDIA_ROOT =  BASE_DIR / 'media' 
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
```

##### for more clone git repo [here](https://github.com/Mahammadhusain/djangodemo--image-demo-.git)